# SQL Server : to column merge from a custom table-defined list

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, nested-loops

Using SQL Server 2012 Express.

I'm building a communications system which emails end users some notifications about upcoming work.  I have a table that stores merge field placeholders and the database field which should populate the data into these placeholders.

I've tried to write a function where I can supply an input string with these placeholders, a unique identifier for that user/machine, and the tenantID, and have it return the string with all the placeholder values replaced with the user's/machine's database values.

I'm running into the error:

> Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

which I've googled and understand why, however I don't know how else I can achieve what I'm trying to do without doing it the way I'm doing it.

The code I've written is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CommsFields]
(
    [ID] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TenantID] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [Placeholder] [VARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,
    [DBField] [VARCHAR](255) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO CommsFields (TenantID, Placeholder, DBField) 
VALUES (1, '@@Email', 'u_PrimarySMTP')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AllMUs]
(
    [MUID] BIGINT,
    u_PrimarySMTP VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO AllMUs (MUID, u_PrimarySMTP) 
VALUES (28228, 'user@domain.com')

CREATE FUNCTION DoFieldMerge
    (@SourceString NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @MUID BIGINT,
     @TenantID BIGINT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultString NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @PHID AS INT

    DECLARE @PHCursor AS CURSOR

    SET @sql = CONCAT('DECLARE @Tenant bigint = ', @TenantID, '; DECLARE @MU bigint = ', @MUID, '; DECLARE @ResultString2 nvarchar(MAX) = ''', @SourceString, ''';')

    SET @PHCursor = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT ID FROM CommsFields

    OPEN @PHCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @PHCursor INTO @PHID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, 'SET @ResultString2 = replace(@ResultString2, ''', (SELECT Placeholder FROM CommsFields WHERE ID = @PHID AND TenantID = @TenantID), ''', (SELECT ISNULL(', (SELECT DBField FROM CommsFields WHERE ID = @PHID AND TenantID = @TenantID), ', '''') FROM AllMUs WHERE MUID = ', @MUID, ' AND TenantID = ', @TenantID, '));')

        FETCH NEXT FROM @PHCursor INTO @PHID
    END

    CLOSE @PHCursor;
    DEALLOCATE @PHCursor;

    --SET @ResultString = @sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ResultString2 nvarchar(MAX) output', @ResultString output;

    RETURN @ResultString
END
GO

SELECT dbo.DoFieldMerge('test @@Email', 28228, 1)
```

I expect the output to be 'test user@domain.com' but instead I get the error

> Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function

If I comment out the 'exec' command near the end, and un-comment the 'SET' command above it, I get the SQL output which I was trying to achieve, and if I run this I get a correct result, but I need to run the contents of `@sql` within the function and return just the resulting `@ResultString`.

I've also tried searching for a code snippet that acts as a custom column merger in SQL, but I'm getting so many results which are nothing to do with what I'm really wanting.

Comment: Does this need to be a function as opposed to a stored procedure returning an output parameter? I didn't see any context on how you're using it.

Comment: Hi, I guess it could be - not sure how to re-write this as a stored procedure though sorry  : /

I have a stored procedure which runs through entries in a table to deliver emails, but essentially all that's stored in that table is the MUID (same as above), the TenantID, the date/time to deliver and the email template to use.  What i'll be doing within that stored procedure is passing the email template contents to this function, where it'll be populated with the database data for that MUID, then used as the email body

Comment: Take a look at this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017#returning-data-using-an-output-parameter. Seems like you could get the string you want out as an Output parameter from a stored procedure as opposed to a returned value from a function.

Comment: Okie doke, thanks for this.  I've rewritten it as a stored proc and it appears to be working in a way I can use now.  Not 100% ideal because I can't use it inline in a query like I could with a function, but hey at least it's working!  Thanks Jeff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here was to instead use a stored procedure with an output parameter.  My final SQL ended up as follow:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DoMerge]
    @SourceString nvarchar(MAX)
    , @MUID bigint
    , @TenantID bigint
    , @ResultString nvarchar(MAX) output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;



    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @PHID as INT
    DECLARE @PHCursor as CURSOR

    SET @sql = CONCAT('DECLARE @Tenant bigint = ', @TenantID, '; DECLARE @MU bigint = ', @MUID, '; DECLARE @ResultString2 nvarchar(MAX) = ''', @SourceString, ''';')

    SET @PHCursor = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT ID FROM CommsFields

    OPEN @PHCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @PHCursor INTO @PHID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN

        SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, 'SET @ResultString2 = replace(@ResultString2, ''', (SELECT CONCAT((SELECT TemplateFieldMarker FROM Config), Placeholder) FROM CommsFields WHERE ID = @PHID AND TenantID = @TenantID), ''', (SELECT ISNULL(', (SELECT DBField FROM CommsFields WHERE ID = @PHID AND TenantID = @TenantID), ', '''') FROM AllMUs WHERE MUID = ', @MUID, ' AND TenantID = ', @TenantID, '));')

        FETCH NEXT FROM @PHCursor INTO @PHID

    END

    CLOSE @PHCursor;
    DEALLOCATE @PHCursor;

    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ' SELECT @ResultString2')

    exec (@sql)

END
```